# auto-complete for sdl in emacs

Tags: c++, sdl, emacs24

How do I set up auto-complete & auto-suggestion in Emacs24 for SDL1.2. I have already configured yasnippet, CEDET & EDE mode in emacs.. Here is my .emacs file. My SDL headers are located into /usr/include/sdl

```
(require 'package)
(add-to-list 'package-archives '("melpa" . "http://melpa.milkbox.net/packages/"))
(package-initialize)

; start auto-complete with emacs
(require 'auto-complete)
; do default config for auto-complete
(require 'auto-complete-config)
(ac-config-default)
; start yasnippet with emacs
(require 'yasnippet)
(yas-global-mode 1)
; let's define a function which initializes auto-complete-c-headers and gets called for c/c++ hooks
(defun my:ac-c-header-init ()
(require 'auto-complete-c-headers)
(add-to-list 'ac-sources 'ac-source-c-headers)
(add-to-list 'achead:include-directories '"/usr/include/c++/4.8")
)
; now let's call this function from c/c++ hooks
(add-hook 'c++-mode-hook 'my:ac-c-header-init)
(add-hook 'c-mode-hook 'my:ac-c-header-init)
; Fix the iedit bug
(define-key global-map (kbd "C-c ;") 'iedit-mode)
(require 'google-c-style)
(add-hook 'c-mode-common-hook 'google-set-c-style)
(add-hook 'c-mode-common-hook 'google-make-newline-indent)
; Turn on Semantic
(semantic-mode 1)
(defun my:add-semantic-to-autocomplete()
(add-to-list 'ac-sources 'ac-source-semantic)
)
(add-hook 'c-mode-common-hook 'my:add-semantic-to-autocomplete)

(global-ede-mode 1)
(custom-set-variables
;; custom-set-variables was added by Custom.
;; If you edit it by hand, you could mess it up, so be careful.
 ;; Your init file should contain only one such instance.
 ;; If there is more than one, they won't work right.
'(custom-enabled-themes (quote (monokai)))
'(custom-safe-themes (quote    ("bd115791a5ac6058164193164fd1245ac9dc97207783eae036f0bfc9ad9670e0" default)))
 '(package-archives (quote (("melpa" . "http://melpa.milkbox.net/packages/"))))
'(scroll-bar-mode nil)
'(show-paren-mode t)
'(tool-bar-mode nil))
(custom-set-faces
;; custom-set-faces was added by Custom.
;; If you edit it by hand, you could mess it up, so be careful.
;; Your init file should contain only one such instance.
;; If there is more than one, they won't work right.
'(default ((t (:family "Ubuntu Mono" :foundry "unknown" :slant normal :weight bold         :height 113 :width normal)))))
```